# Quick plotting question regarding MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to plot a 5x5 matrix (call is `a` for now) composed of either +1 or -1. I want to plot this using a heat map such that a black square will represent a (-1) and a white square will represent a (+1). I think the appropriate command to should be `image`, however if I just do `image(a)` I don't get much...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instead use the function [IMAGESC](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imagesc.html) so it scales the display of the image values to the full range of the colormap. Then you can use the functions [COLORMAP](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/colormap.html) and GRAY to display the image as black (-1) and white (+1):

```
imagesc(a);
colormap(gray);
```

Comment: Oh you're good, man. Thanks a lot. will mark a check as soon as time lets me

Answer (score 1):

Create a two-color colormap and offset the matrix values to fall within the colormap range:

```
>> image(a+1);
>> colormap([0 0 0; 1 1 1]);
```